# Using context reference after activity be finished

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have a complete button in page, when user click button, it will start an async task and pass the activity context into it, then finish the activity to dismiss the activity view.

What will happen if the activity be finished but the background task still need to use the context reference passed in? will it have any concerns? or have alternative/better way for this kind of situation.

any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: You can use android services for the background processing and broadcast receivers to get data from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, in this situation you better go for service instead of asynctask. In your case, Service should stop itself once task is finished.
2. Even if you go for asynctask, try to use application context that you can get from activity context as below:

   ```
   activity_context.getApplicationContext();
   ```

   The application context will be there even if activity is finished and also it will avoid memory leak.
3. And if you want to make the asynctask run safely even if activity is finished, then try not to update any UI in postExecute(..) method as it will run on the UI of the activity which is already finished leading to exception. Try to do only any background task inside doInBackground(...) which runs on different thread.

Hope this answers your question.